# illegal offset with foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using foreach and I am getting illegal offset, the items are printed successfully in a table, but with an additional variable `i`, not knowing where it came from ! The error says illegal offset. what I've done wrong ?

```
<table border ="1">
   <tr>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>size</th>
     <th>color</th>
     <th>price</th>
     <th>quantity</th>
   </tr>

<?php
     session_start();
     if (isset($_POST["btnac"])){
         if (isset($_SESSION["incart"])){
            $item_aid = array_column($_SESSION["incart"],"item_id");
            if(!in_array($_GET["itemid"],$item_aid)){
                $countitems = count($_SESSION["incart"]);
                $items = array(
                          'item_id'      => $_GET["itemid"],
                          'item_name'    =>  $_POST["itemname"],
                          'item_price'   =>  $_POST["price"],
                          'item_color'   =>  $_POST["color"],
                          'item_size'    =>   $_POST["size"],
                          'item_quantity' =>  $_POST["quantity"]);

                $_SESSION["incart"][$countitems] = $items;
            }else{
                 echo '<script>alert("Item previously added")</script>';
                 echo '<script>window.location("index.php")</script>';
            }

         }else {
             $items = array(
                          'item_id'      => $_GET["itemid"],
                          'item_name'    =>  $_POST["itemname"],
                          'item_price'   =>  $_POST["price"],
                          'item_color'   =>  $_POST["color"],
                          'item_size'    =>   $_POST["size"],
                          'item_quantity' =>  $_POST["quantity"] );

                          $_SESSION["incart"][0] = $items;

         }
     }
?>
  <?php 
      if(!empty($_SESSION["incart"])){
         $sumpay = 0;
         foreach($_SESSION["incart"] as $select => $val){
         ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?php  echo $val["item_name"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $val["item_size"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $val["item_color"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $val["item_price"];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $val["item_quantity"];?></td>
          </tr>
     <?php
         }
       }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: i can't find variable `i` in your provided code.

Comment: The  i comes with the error which is illegal offset

Comment: did you try to `print_r $_SESSION["incart"]` and `$val` ?

Comment: how to do that ?\

Comment: put before `if(!empty($_SESSION["incart"])){
         $sumpay = 0;`  this `echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION["incart"]);echo "</pre>";`

Comment: and check what is you getting in `$_SESSION["incart"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION["incart"][0] = $items;
```

Should be:

```
$_SESSION["incart"] = $items;
```